# MVC3 Custom validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with property

```
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public List<Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
```

I want to validate that List should be greater then 0

Suggest me the code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Atleast one phone number is required
/// </summary>
public sealed class DemographicPhoneNumberRequiredCheck : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
       ???????
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Count` or `Any`:

```
   public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
       var PhoneNumbers = value as List<Phone>;
       if (PhoneNumbers != null) 
       {
          return PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0;
       }

       return false;
    }
```

Or:

```
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
       var PhoneNumbers = value as List<Phone>;
       if (PhoneNumbers != null) 
       {
          return PhoneNumbers.Any();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice and simple :)

Comment: I am not sure how he can get PhoneNumbers in validation attribute directly. Haven't u missed cast somethere?

Comment: Unless I am missing something really simple, this is not going to compile. `PhoneNumbers` are not available inside attribute implementation.

Comment: just cast object "value" to List<Phone>

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have the value in your method:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var phoneNumbers = value as List<Phone>;
    if(phoneNumbers != null) 
    {
        // perform the validation
    }
}
```